# Exchange 2010 Server Crashed need to know how to mount Old DB

Tags: exchange-2010, disaster-recovery

I HAD a Crash on my Exchange 2010 server so I redid the whole thing removed all entries out of AD
So new server is installed with fresh installation of Exchange 2010 now my problem:

I still have the original Copy of the DB folder how and what will the steps be to mount this db

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you didn't re-install Exchange with the `setup /m:RecoverServer` switch? That would probably have made your life **much** easier.

Have you tried simply replacing the current (presumably empty) .edb files with the ones you have from the backup? Exchange 2010 has something called [Database Portability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876873.aspx), but I'm not sure how that would work in this instance.

It's quite possible that you've totally trashed your Exchange environment by making changes directly to Active Directory, and if that's the case you might need to speak to Microsoft PSS - however I suspect that since you've manually edited Active Directory they might not be able to help you either.

Comment: Hmm... The situation called for a scalpel but the OP used a machete. We learn more from our failures than our successes.